# Linux kill subproccess of already stop parent

Tags: linux

I am a Linux starter. 
I have an multi threads application running on server. To stop the app, I executed command `application_name stop`. The app have been stopped. But later I realized its sub processes still running and process on my database. Because there are other applications can not be stopped on server, so I can not restart it. What can I do to kill these sub processes without restarting server?

Comment: `killall processname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of this can be managed through the app server depending on what you're using. With WebLogic, GlassFish, JBoss and Tomcat, you can shutdown your specific app, or remove it and reinstall it without disrupting the other applications on the server.

The `application_name stop` is very ambiguous, it sounds like shell wrapper for doing this kind of shutdown already.

As Joenas was stating, I recommend using `kill $PGID` (or  an explicit `kill -15  $PGID`). This gives the subprocess a chance at shutting down properly, depending on how it's been programmed. Then use `ps aux` (the dash isn't not required)  and then checking if the subprocess has died. If it still lingers for more than a few seconds, then do the unforgiving `kill -9 $PGID`.

PS. If you the one maintaining these subprocesses, you may want to rethink your design, and maybe use threads, since you expect them to shutdown with the application.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correct:
With the command ps you can find all process running, use the flags -aux to see all processes running.

```
ps -aux
```

You can then use the Process Group ID (PGID) to kill the prosses.

```
kill $PGID 
Or
kill -9 $PGID
```

See for more info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124127/kill-all-descendant-processes